# Send image to server in offline/online

Tags: android, http, android-intent, ftp

I've a process to send an image to server as per client/end-user wish(pick) from gallery and upload. But the task is to send an image file from an application, even-though user don't have an internet connection and it should send a file when he/she get it(internet connection again/back). I request you people to suggest some idea and it will helpful if I get snippet of code/sample. Thank you!

Comment: First try something, then ask for help... Google is your friend.. You could have started with "how to detect internet connection on android" for an example.  Look into broadcastreceivers.

Comment: yeah! I tried almost so came up here... I can upload the file in server.. my question is to perform a task later if user doen't have internet connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

1. Make an android service which gets started when application tries to send files but internet is not available.
2. Android service will wait for internet connectivity availability.
3. Store the http url and image uri for every upload request made during this time in SharedPreference.
4. When network becomes available fetch upload request from shared preference and make request one by one.

Hope this helps.